# ¿Como puedo insertar una variable que haga referencia a una tabla dentro de una consulta en php? select * from $tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Necesito realizar una consulta, al nombre de una tabla que recibo por POST, el problema es que de la forma que la realizo, me da error y desconozco de que forma puedo realizar la consulta haciendo referencia al nombre de la tabla por medio de una variable.

```
<?php

include "../conexion.php";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $nombreServicio = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $nombreServicio = $nombreServicio['servicio'];
    $datos = explode("-", $nombreServicio);

    $nombre=$datos[1]."_ABS";

    $sel = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM '$nombre' ");

    $consulta = array();
    foreach ($sel as $fila) {
    array_push($consulta,$fila);
     }

     echo json_encode($consulta);

     $sel->close();
     $conexion->close();

}
?>
```

de ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta concatenando la variable asi:

```
$sel = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM " . $nombre);
```

Answer (score 0):

O puedes poner el string de esta manera

```
$sel = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM $nombre;");
```

al estar la variable entre comillas dobles, PHP la interpretará